# What are the virtual key codes for the Windows 8 specific multimedia keys?

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-8, keyboard

I have a [Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/sculpt-ergonomic-desktop/L5V-00001) which has additional function keys.

See also my question on SuperUser, ["What are the functions of the multimedia keys?"](https://superuser.com/questions/753917/what-are-the-functions-of-the-multimedia-keys).

There are keys for the charm bar functions and some I have yet to identify.

Since Windows 7 does not have these functions I thought I could write an application to do something useful with these keys.

What are the virtual key codes for these keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out on my own using a simple test application:

```
F5  = Search                         = 16 91 132 = VK_SHIFT   + VK_LWIN + VK_F21
F6  = Share                          = 18 91 132 = VK_MENU    + VK_LWIN + VK_F21
F7  = Devices                        = 17 91 132 = VK_CONTROL + VK_LWIN + VK_F21
F8  = Settings                       =    91 132 =              VK_LWIN + VK_F21
F9  = Display switch                 = 17 91   8 = VK_CONTROL + VK_LWIN + VK_BACK
F10 = Flip3D
F11 = Horizontal display orientation = 18 91 133 = VK_MENU    + VK_LWIN + VK_F22
F12 = Vertical display orientation   = 17 91 134 = VK_CONTROL + VK_LWIN + VK_F23
```

F10 invokes Flip3D on Windows 7, so without installing a keyboard hook I can not figure out what key combination is triggered.